# Don't display empty grouped cell tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm doing a similar view to *View Contact* in Contacts.app, meaning I have multiple fields that are not required (second work phone, second email, etc.) under different sections (Phones, Emails, etc.).

When some fields are empty, I don't want to display them, when all the fields are empty under a section, I don't want to display this section. Also, some of the cells have action on them, like when tapping on a phone number cell, it calls the number displayed. Currently, these actions are manually handled in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with basic ifs depending of the cell position.

I can't find an elegant solution to do all this... I tried an array of dictionaries (each cell) for each section but things rapidly went messy. Also, since the order of the rows is never the same, I can't easily with ifs handle all the actions in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method based on the cell position.

Oh and I'm using Core Data under the hood.

Anybody had to do something similar and is willing to share his thoughts?

Thanks!

Exemple of my static ifs setup right now to differentiate cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        // Custom actions here
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        // Other actions here
        [self showMailComposeWithEmail:cell.textLabel.text];
    }
}
```

And another method using indexPath to differentiate styles and behaviors:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = self.contact.phone;
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = self.contact.email;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code from where you are adding data

Comment: What do you mean from where I'm adding data?

Comment: Are you adding the data to an array or dictionary?

Comment: I removed all this, back to the white board, currently everything is static, optional fields are just empty cells.

Comment: Make an array which counts count of your sections(phones,emails). Make a dictionary which maintains all values of 2ns phone,work,etc. Store the Primary vales at index 0 of table and rest at 1,2 etc.

Comment: I did something similar but was not really pleased with the solution. And how would you maintain the cells action?

Comment: Here's a little help to clean the different actions performed by the different table cells: When you subclass them, you can add an invisible button above the text, or a similar entity and make it perform a certain action defined in the custom UITableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Take a dictionary and when you add object to that dictionary make sure that the data in it is not blank. Add it data in dictionary for keys as below:

```
Phones - key 0^0 (it means at 0 section 0 row)
WorkPhone - key 0^1(it means at 0 section 1st row)
Emails - key1^0 (1 section 0th row) and so on...
```

And at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` fetch this value as

```
[dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d^%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]];
```

Hope thats clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. couple questions: How would yo do it for the method `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. Also, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` have ifs in them, how would you differentiate cells since I can't rely on the indexPath anymore (now the email can be first if cellphone is empty and not displayed, etc. etc.). See my edited answer for some of my current code. thanks!

Comment: If you could add a bit more code based of my edited answer I'll accept that answer right away, I really appreciate your time, thank you.

Comment: Sure i can help you.But can u show me where and how you fill data in contact array

Comment: It's not filled in an array. it's a core data entity!

Comment: Which array? I'm using a core data attribute that has only phone And email properties. Feel free to use fictive data to show me the big picture :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22185/discussion-between-allaire-and-dhara)